# Creating 3D polyline in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d

I have a csv file containing a breakline points' coordinates and their elevation.

How can I create a 3d polyline from these points?

The CSV file looks like this:

```
  X              Y         z
384282.6    244807.4    22.1807
384376.4    244791.2    12.6306
384467.5    244773.5    12.634
384535.7    244745      12.5274
384593.4    244701.9    12.6257
```

Comment: What does your CSV file look like?  Please include a few test rows from it in your question.

Comment: It is just a simple csv file, contains three columns, x column ,y column and z column.

Comment: Please **edit** the question in response to comments requesting clarification.  The answer to your question really does depend on the exact data format, so a data sample is not an unreasonable request.

Comment: Third-party links are not often followed. Please include five rows of the file **in the question**

Answer (score 3):

Add XY Data to map (ensure to include Z-coordinate as well)

Export result to Shapefile or a Geodatabase Feature Class

Use Points to Line tool to convert the points to a polyline

Because you included Z-Coordinate the resulting polyline is a 3D polyline

Using your data, here is the result in ArcScene (exaggerated 10x):
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jakub for your response.                                                           How can I add this breakline to a raster. I have a raster for the same area, I want to adjust the raster elevation along this breakline.

Answer (score 1):

The [ASCII 3D to Feature Class Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/ascii-3d-to-feature-class.htm) can also be used for this task. Using the sample data above, it produces the output below. Set **Output Feature Class Type** to **POLYLINE**

[image]